# aws autoscalling causing automatic logout in Laravel

Tags: amazon-ec2, laravel-5.6, php-7.1

Few days back, We implemented AWS auto scaling and after that we started facing automatic logout problem in Laravel, We changed session storing from file to database like this

```
BROADCAST_DRIVER=redis
CACHE_DRIVER=file
SESSION_DRIVER=redis
QUEUE_DRIVER=database

REDIS_HOST=<Private IP of MYSQL + REDIS server>
REDIS_PASSWORD=null
REDIS_PORT=6379
```

Following is our server architecture.

[image]

As a solution, I increased session lifetime in config/session.php, which is not a good solution and it did not work. I tried to find cause in code as well but I could not find any clue.

This problem is huge in my website right now. Can anyone suggest what could be the problem and possible solutions?

Comment: is the sticky sessions enabled in the application load balancer?

Comment: @Conti I don't remember right now but trying to cross-check it but not getting it in my load balancer

Comment: I enabled sticky session, It solved problem to some extent but it is not fully solved.